Building tensorflow (release 2.13.0 or earlier) from source
I am building tensorflow(release 2.13.0) from source. I have the following requirements meant(Python 3.8-3.11, Clang 16.0.0, Bazel 5.3.0).
I still face errors with bazel build --config=opt --define=no_tensorflow_py_deps=true //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package

Thanks @TheCableGUI, I did all the above. However, Clang 16.0.0 is not available for Ubuntu 22.04.5. I installed Clang 16.0.1 with an assupmtion it would be compatible. The installation runs and terminates after hours.
Is there a work around this?
I appreciate all the replies.
Peace.


Ensure that the version of Bazel you're using is compatible with TensorFlow 2.13.0. You can verify the version using:

bazel --version


Ensure all dependencies (e.g., system libraries, Python packages) required by TensorFlow are installed. Specifically, check the Python Development Environment:


Ensure that you have the development headers for Python installed for the version you're using.

On Ubuntu:
 sudo apt-get install python3-dev
On macOS: Ensure that the Command Line Tools (CLT) are installed using xcode-select --install.

Numpy: TensorFlow requires a specific version of numpy, so it’s good to install it first with the following:
pip install numpy==1.21.5


Make sure Clang 16.0.0 is correctly installed and available on your system. You can check its version by running:
clang --version

Also, ensure that the environment variables CC and CXX are pointing to Clang:
export CC=clang
export CXX=clang++


If there are leftover artifacts from previous builds, they can cause errors. Clean the Bazel cache:

bazel clean


Make sure you're building TensorFlow with the correct configuration. Since you mentioned using  --config=opt and --define=no_tensorflow_py_deps=true, verify if these flags are appropriate for your build:

--config=opt:
This flag enables optimizations for the build.
--define=no_tensorflow_py_deps=true:
This skips building Python dependencies, which can be useful for certain types of builds, but it may also cause issues if Python bindings are necessary.

To get more information, you can try building with additional debugging output:

bazel build --config=opt --verbose_failures --sandbox_debug //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package 

This will provide more detailed error messages that may help identify the problem

Check GitHub Tensorflow tickets and open one if not.

Use a pre built Tensorflow pkg.


Sorry man. Honestly, I would just try to emulate the dev environment given to you by the original Tensorflow creators.
